# Comparing values of textview & editText as 1 = one in Android

Tags: android

i have one textview, one edittext and one button in my app.
    i want, the textview numbers(1-10) change randomly and user enter the same number but in character, as if textview display 7 so user must enter the value as seven. if it is same then textview change again randomly and new value should be displayed textview and the same process again if value is wrong so "try again" message should be displayed...
    **here's my xml code..**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvShow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:text="5"
        android:textSize="100sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnShow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:text="Check" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnShow"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="26dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Spelling"  >
        <requestFocus/>

        </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Here is my java code...**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    TextView tv;
    EditText etTextField;
    Button btnCheck;
    String val;

    Random rand= new Random();
    int a1 = rand.nextInt(10)+1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvShow);
        etTextField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        btnCheck = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShow);
        btnCheck.setOnClickListener(this);
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch(v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.btnShow:

        a1 = rand.nextInt(10)+1;
        tv.setText(Integer.toString(a1));
        val = etTextField.getText().toString();

        if(a1==4 && val.equals("four"))
        {

            Toast t = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "4", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            t.show();

        }
        val = etTextField.getText().toString();
         if(a1==7 && val.equals("seven"))
        {

            Toast t = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "7", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            t.show();   

        }
        val = etTextField.getText().toString();
         if(a1==8 && val.equals("eight"))
        {

            Toast t = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "8", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            t.show();

        }

        break;



        }//swtich
    }//onclick

}//class body
```

Comment: And what's your problem specifically?

Comment: only number (textview) changes...not taking value from textfiled and as well no comparison

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Updated your whole code , This will work for you

**Activity**

```
public class ActivityMain extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    TextView tv;
    EditText etTextField;
    Button btnCheck, btnReset;
    String val;
    int a1; 
    Random rand = new Random();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvShow);
        etTextField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        btnCheck = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShow);
        btnReset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnreset);
        btnCheck.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnReset.setOnClickListener(this);
        a1 = rand.nextInt(10) + 1;
        tv.setText(Integer.toString(a1));
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnShow:

            tv.setText(Integer.toString(a1));

            val = etTextField.getText().toString().trim();

            System.out.println("integer is " + a1);
            System.out.println("value  is " + val);

            if (a1 == 1 && val.equalsIgnoreCase("one")) {

                Toast t = Toast.makeText(ActivityMain.this, "1",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                t.show();

            }

            else if (a1 == 2 && val.equalsIgnoreCase("two")) {

                Toast t = Toast.makeText(ActivityMain.this, "2",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                t.show();

            }

            else if (a1 == 3 && val.equalsIgnoreCase("Three")) {

                Toast t = Toast.makeText(ActivityMain.this, "3",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                t.show();

            }

            else if (a1 == 5 && val.equalsIgnoreCase("five")) {

                Toast t = Toast.makeText(ActivityMain.this, "5",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                t.show();

            }

            else if (a1 == 4 && val.equalsIgnoreCase("four")) {

                Toast t = Toast.makeText(ActivityMain.this, "4",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                t.show();

            }

            else if (a1 == 7 && val.equalsIgnoreCase("seven")) {

                Toast t = Toast.makeText(ActivityMain.this, "7",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                t.show();

            }

            else if (a1 == 8 && val.equalsIgnoreCase("eight")) {

                Toast t = Toast.makeText(ActivityMain.this, "8",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                t.show();

            } else if (a1 == 6 && val.equalsIgnoreCase("six")) {

                Toast t = Toast.makeText(ActivityMain.this, "6",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                t.show();

            } else if (a1 == 9 && val.equalsIgnoreCase("nine")) {

                Toast t = Toast.makeText(ActivityMain.this, "9",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                t.show();

            } else if (a1 == 10 && val.equalsIgnoreCase("ten")) {

                Toast t = Toast.makeText(ActivityMain.this, "10",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                t.show();

            } else {

            Toast t = Toast.makeText(ActivityMain.this, "Try again",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            t.show();


             a1 = rand.nextInt(10) + 1;
             tv.setText(Integer.toString(a1));
             etTextField.setText("");
        }

            break;
        case R.id.btnreset:
            // update text here
             a1 = rand.nextInt(10) + 1;
             tv.setText(Integer.toString(a1));
             etTextField.setText("");

            break;
        }// swtich
    }// onclick
}// class body
```

**Layout file**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvShow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:text="5"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="100sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnShow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:text="Check" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnreset"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnShow"
        android:text="Reset" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnShow"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="26dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Spelling" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Yes you can control this in a single button, Paste the code of Reset button listener in else clause below try again message.

Comment: Thanks a lot Brother..........one little help more please...can i control it one button "check" as when values match and i press "check" button so randomly come next value on textview and same process contiue.......!!

Comment: Brother i cut the code of reset button and pasted it in else clause but textview is not changing...

Comment: I have updated my answer, Just copy and paste the same and if my answer helped you , Select this as an answer by clicking on the  tick arrow below 0.

Answer (score 0):

Switch: case is one way to do this. But the best way is to create an hashmap,something like this:

Create a xml with your values:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <string-array name="numbers_string">
            <item>one</item>
            <item>two</item>//...

        </string-array>

        <integer-array name="numbers_int">
            <item>1</item>
            <item>2</item>//....
        </integer-array>
    </resources>
```

And code:

**heres is the code as you need it...**

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

switch(v.getId())
{
case R.id.btnShow:

    a1 = rand.nextInt(10)+1;
    tv.setText(Integer.toString(a1));
    val = etTextField.getText().toString();


    String[] numbersString = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.numbers_string);
    int[] numbersInt = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.numbers_int);

  //the error that you had happened because this should be <int,string> , now it works  
HashMap<Integer, String> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
for (int i = 0; i < numbersString.length; i++) 
    {
    myMap.put(numbersInt[i], numbersString[i]);
    }

   if (val.equalsIgnoreCase(myMap.get(a1))) {
     Toast t = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+a1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
      t.show();
   }
  else{
      Toast t = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
      t.show();
  }

  break;


}}}
```

Comment: @user2877967 Where is your updated code? what is the crash error?

Comment: @user2877967 This works without errors, can you try it know? ;)